# How to have 2 Different Liquibase Deployments on the same source object

Tags: liquibase

I am complete Noobie in Liquibase (and jenkins) deployments.

We have a SQL table which can be modified by 2 separate git repositories. We have one `liquibase` based deployment for this table for each of the git repos.

**ISSUE:**
Liquibase will try to update the `DATAGBASECHANGELOG` after each deployment. Thus breaking the cycle of continuity between 2 commits in the same git repo.

E.g.

We have a `table A`, the script for which is `A.sql` and it is in two repos `X` and `Y`. The table script can be modified in either of the two repos X or Y. Now if I do the **first** deployment using the `repo X`, **second** using `repo Y` and then **change** the file `A.sql` in `repo X`, then **next** `repo X` deployment with fail because of mismatched `changesets`.

What we think can solve this is that we need to have 2 different `DATABASECHANGELOG` tables for each repository deployment?

Any help or pointers will be of great help.

Comment: A guess: The mismatched changesets might be because the file `A.sql` has different paths in `repo X` and `repo Y`. Liquibase uses the complete path for the generation of the id to uniquely identify changesets. If this is the case you could use [`relativeToChangelogFile`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html) attribute on the changesets to make liquibase not use the whole path when generating the id.

Comment: Are changes in the two repos independent of each other, or are there dependences? Also, does A.sql in X and Y contain the full CREATE TABLE statements? Can you give examples of your change sets and changelog files?